# Solving for a vector that is orthogonal to two other vectors.

Tags: linear-algebra, vectors

Suppose $[a, b, c]^T$ is orthogonal to both $[3, 4, -2]^T$ and $[4, 2, -3]^T$ and $a, b, c$ are not all zero. Which of the following is true?

A. $\frac{a}{b} = -5/7$

B. $\frac{b}{c} = -1$

C. $\frac{c}{a} = -1/6$

D. $\frac{a}{c} = 4/5$

E. There is not solution.

I know the solution is D, but I am having trouble coming to that answer. I tried making a system where $3a + 4b -2c = 0$ and $4a + 2b -3c = 0$ because the dot product must be zero. However, that only gives me the solution to $a$, $b$. How do I get $c$?

Comment: Well, you should have a free variable, since there's a whole 1 dimensional space of vectors orthogonal to two others (a plane). But you can use the cross product to get an ideal one, and then apply a scalar... I think that's similar or equivalent to what you may have done.

Comment: Use $c=1$: whatever its value you'll find vectors perpendicular to the ones given.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the equations are
$$ 3a + 4b -2c = 0\ \text{ (I)}$$
$$ 4a + 2b -3c = 0\ \text{ (II)}$$
then notice that if we multiply equation (II) by $-2$ and add it to the equation (I), we get
$$-5a+4c = 0$$
which gives $\dfrac{a}{c} = \dfrac{4}{5}$.

Comment: That makes sense. Thanks.

Comment: You're welcome :)